How is hardhat a dev dependency?
I know this is a beginner question, but I haven't grasped this particular package being a dev dependency. Aren't we including functions from hardhat in our deploy scripts? And I assume the main objective of hardhat projects is to deploy contracts. So anyone wanting to run (not develop) our code must install hardhat.
But this hardhat tutorial page instructs to install hardhat as a dev dependency.
I must be missing something.

Installing Hardhat as a dev dependency means that it’s only required for development purposes, such as compiling, testing, and deploying contracts.
Once the development process is complete and you want to deploy your code for others to run, users will need to install Hardhat separately to interact with your contracts.
This separation ensures that your production environment remains lean and only includes the necessary dependencies for execution.

So what is my production environment? Only the contracts? Well since
the js cannot be deployed on a blockchain, the deployed artifacts will
be lean either way. Isn't it?

Your production environment typically refers to the environment where your application or smart contracts are deployed and actively used by users or other systems. While the deployed artifacts on the blockchain are indeed lean, the production environment may include other components such as front-end applications, backend services, databases, or other infrastructure necessary for the functioning of your dApp.
By installing Hardhat as a dev dependency, you keep your production environment focused on the essential components needed for running your dApp, without including development tools and dependencies that are only required during the development phase. This helps to keep your production environment lightweight and optimized for performance.

So what is my production environment? Only the contracts? Well since the js cannot be deployed on a blockchain, the deployed artifacts will be lean either way. Isn't it?

@HosseinEbrahimi, I’ve added the response in my answer. Please check.
